# Return text value from multiple drop down menus

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to return the value of a drop down select box into a text input.  Currently, I can modify only the first text box with the drop down selection.  Please see the working example on JSFiddle below.

HTML::

```
    <select id="select1">
<option value="foo">foo</option>
<option value="bar">bar</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="remap" name="out[]" />
<br />
<select id="select1">
<option value="foo">foo</option>
<option value="bar">bar</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="remap" name="out[]" />
```

JQuery::

`$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function(){
        $('select[id^=dropdown_]:not(.ui-dropdown_)').live('change', function(){
            var Data = $(this).val();
            $('#remap_value').val(Data);
        })
    });
});`

Example: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/12eprod/mFWd5/5/)

Comment: That's because ID's are unique, and javascript expects there to be only one single element with the ID `#select1`, and only gets the first one.

Comment: Apologies, this is my first post to stack overflow.  On the jsfiddle i have unique ID's --> <select name="select" id="dropdown_1">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML was invalid, even in your jsFiddle. Your IDs were not unique for your `input`s.

But to make it work, first I changed the IDs of the `input`s to be unique and gave each `select` a class:

```
<select name="select" id="dropdown_1" class="Dropdown">
    ...
</select>
<input type="text" id="remap_value1" name="out[]" />
<br />
<select name="select" id="dropdown_2" class="Dropdown">
    ...
</select>
<input type="text" id="remap_value2" name="out[]" />
```

This will make the selector in jQuery to be much more efficient than the convoluted CSS-based selector you currently have.

Then I modded the jQuery to be hyper-efficient:

```
$(function(){
    $('.Dropdown').on('change', function(){
        $(this).next().val($(this).val());
    })
});
```

To quickly explain the changes to the jQuery:

1. you were double-encapsulating your jQuery, `$(function(){` is shorthand for `$(document).ready({function(){`
2. I made use of `.on()` instead of `.live()`, as live is now deprecated
3. I accessed the class `Dropdown` I created to bind the `change` event
4. I used `.next()` to go to the next HTML element on the same level of the DOM tree as the select item that changed
5. I used `$(this).val()` when plugging in the new text value, avoiding unneeded variable caching

As you can see, with this method you don't even need to have IDs for the inputs that follow, unless you were accessing them for another purpose.

If you were worried about conflicts with another dropdown, you could easily incorporate `.not()` into the selector:

```
$(function(){
    $('.Dropdown').not('.ui-dropdown_').on('change', function(){
        $(this).next().val($(this).val());
    })
});
```

This is actually the preferred use of `not` instead of the CSS usage, per the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).

[jsFiddle to show changes and working example](http://jsfiddle.net/mFWd5/8/)

Comment: Once more... Thanks Again!  It is sometimes tough learning from books and web sites.

Comment: That's why I tried to provide more context instead of just an answer. I figured more information about why it worked would help with future coding endeavors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.next()` to select the proper input.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(function(){
    $('select[id^=dropdown_]:not(.ui-dropdown_)').live('change', function(){
        $(this).next('.remap_value').val($(this).val());
    })
  });
});
```

Edit: You should use class instead of ID for remap_value, since it is invalid to have multiple elements with the same ID. My answer has also been updated for efficiency.

```
<input type="text" class="remap_value" name="out[]" />
```